# Stage not being drawn

Tags: java, libgdx, stage, scene2d

I'm pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this isn't working.

I'm just trying to put together a basic Options menu and for some reason the Stage doesn't seem to be drawing the actors.

I've tried putting the same actor creation code into another project with a working stage and it draws fine, and I've gone over both this and the working project with a fine tooth comb looking for anything I'm missing and as far as I can tell everything stage-related in the working code is in this one too, yet all I get with this OptionsScreen.java is a blank black screen.

Here's the java file in question, OptionsScreen.java

```
package com.kittykazoo.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox.CheckBoxStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.kittykazoo.gamehelpers.ScreenHandler;

public class OptionsScreen implements Screen {

    private ScreenHandler sh;

    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skin;

    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private Label sfxVolValue;
    private Label musicVolValue;

    public OptionsScreen(ScreenHandler sh) {

        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "Attached");

        this.sh = sh;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 960, 600);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        createOptions();

    }

    private void createOptions() {

        skin = new Skin();

        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(100, 100, Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        pixmap.fill();

        skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));

        BitmapFont bfont = new BitmapFont();
        bfont.scale(1);
        skin.add("default", bfont);

        CheckBoxStyle checkBoxStyle = new CheckBoxStyle();
        checkBoxStyle.checkboxOff = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.WHITE);
        checkBoxStyle.checkboxOffDisabled = skin.newDrawable("white",
                Color.DARK_GRAY);
        checkBoxStyle.checkboxOn = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.WHITE);
        checkBoxStyle.checkboxOnDisabled = skin.newDrawable("white",
                Color.DARK_GRAY);
        checkBoxStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.WHITE);
        checkBoxStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
        skin.add("default", checkBoxStyle);

        TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.BLUE);
        textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
        skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);

        final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Checkbox here", checkBoxStyle);
        checkBox.setPosition(100, 100);
        stage.addActor(checkBox);

        final TextButton textButton = new TextButton("UPDATE", textButtonStyle);
        textButton.setPosition(200, 200);
        stage.addActor(textButton);

        textButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                textButton.setText("Submitting...");
                sh.hideOptions();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        // Black background
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "resizing");
        stage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(width, height));
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "show called");
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "hide called");
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "pause called");
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        Gdx.app.log("OptionsScreen", "resume called");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
    }

}
```

I assume I must be missing something super obvious. If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.setViewport(new StretchViewport(width, height));
}
```

This is completely wrong in many ways. First of all, you do not want to create a new viewport on every resize, because of the Garbage Collector.

Furthermore creating a `StretchViewport` with the new screen width and height renders the StretchViewport useless, because it will basically behave like a `ScreenViewport` instead. Make sure to read the [Viewports wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to understand how the different viewports work.

And last but not least, the reason why your stage is not drawn is also hidden within that. A UI `Stage` needs to have the camera centered, otherwise it won't be rendered correctly.

So what you want to do instead is the following:

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it right out :) And thanks for the wiki article link, I'll give that a read-through.